# Content-type is not being set when submitting form

Tags: html, forms, go, multipartform-data

I am attempting to submit a form from a page (using Bootstrap) to a Go server. Everything is being routed correctly, but when the Go function attempts to parse the multipart form data, it throws an error claiming content type isn't multipart/form-data.

Here is the HTML

```
<form action="/api/submitPost" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data"> 
    <div class="form-check">
        <input type="checkbox" name="rules" class="form-check-input" id="rulesCheck1" value="1">
        <label class="form-check-label" for="rulesCheck1">
            I have read the <a href="/rules">rules</a>
        </label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" name="subject" class="form-control" id="subjectInput" placeholder="Subject">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" name="body" class="form-control" id="bodyInput" placeholder="Body">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group-sm justify-content-between">
        <input type="file" name="file" class="file" id="fileInput" data-browse-on-zone-click="true">
        <input type="hidden" name="boardName" value="{{ .board }}">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

Here is the Go function (up until the error is returned)

```
func submitPost(r *http.Request) error {
    maxSize := int64(32 << 20) // 32MB
    if err := r.ParseMultipartForm(maxSize); err != nil {
        for name, values := range r.Header {
            for _, value := range values {
                println("\t", name, ":", value)
            }
        }
        return errors.New("error parsing, " + err.Error())
    }

    ...

}
```

and here is the output (sorry for the weird syntax highlighting, I don't know how to fix it). It appears content-type isn't being set at all.

```
         Accept : text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9
         Sec-Fetch-User : ?1
         Sec-Fetch-Dest : document
         Referer : http://localhost/tech
         Connection : keep-alive
         Cache-Control : max-age=0
         Upgrade-Insecure-Requests : 1
         User-Agent : [my user agent]
         Sec-Fetch-Site : same-origin
         Sec-Fetch-Mode : navigate
         Accept-Encoding : gzip, deflate, br
         Accept-Language : en-US,en;q=0.9
2020/09/14 11:38:52 err: error parsing, request Content-Type isn't multipart/form-data
```

Comment: The content type header is not set because the client not send a request body. Did the server redirect the request?

Answer (score 0):

Well, shortly after posting this, I solved the problem by adding a "/" at the end of the form action link. This is my final form.

```
<form action="/api/submitPost/" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data"> 
    <div class="form-check">
        <input type="checkbox" name="rules" class="form-check-input" id="rulesCheck1" value="1">
        <label class="form-check-label" for="rulesCheck1">
            I have read the <a href="/rules">rules</a>
        </label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" name="subject" class="form-control" id="subjectInput" placeholder="Subject">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" name="body" class="form-control" id="bodyInput" placeholder="Body">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group-sm justify-content-between">
        <input type="file" name="file" class="file" id="fileInput" data-browse-on-zone-click="true">
        <input type="hidden" name="boardName" value="{{ .board }}">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
    </div>
</form>
```